# posix semaphore trouble

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, semaphore

I supposed that my program should work like this:
1) initializing unnamed semaphore with value = 0
the second value for `sem_init`(..) is 1 so as it said in MAN the semaphore is shared between processes
2) creating child, child waits until semaphore value becomes 1

parent process increases the value of semaphore so the child should exit now
but it doesn't exit really, so that is the problem

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


pid_t child;


void child_proc(sem_t* sem) {
    sem_wait(sem);
    printf("OK\n");
}

void parent_proc(sem_t* sem) {

    sem_post(sem);
    sleep(2);

    int status;
    waitpid(child, &status, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sem_t sem;
    sem_init(&sem, 1, 0);

    child = fork();

    if (0 == child) {
        child_proc(&sem);
        return 0;
    }

    parent_proc(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both processes have a local (not shared) copy of the semaphore structure and changes in one process won't reflect to the other process.

As [the man page also says](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html), if you want to share semaphores across processes, not only do you need to pass a non-zero value to the second argument of `sem_init`, but the `sem_t` structure also needs to exist in an area of shared memory. In your example program, it exists on the stack, which is not shared.

You can have shared memory by using a common file mapping (with `mmap`) or with `shm_open`, notably.

Comment: should i use create shared memory block by myself and put sem_t into it?

Comment: @NinjaTurtle, yeah, that's pretty much what you have to do.

Comment: Ok, after doing it i have another problem: man says that (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html) the shared data must be updated after each change, so i need to call 'msync()' after each semaphore action, yeah?:(

Comment: Yes, if you go the mmap way, you have to call it. At that rate, you might want to use a named semaphore for your purposes.